# How to put the given data into a XML file using Jquery and Ajax?

Tags: php

I have a modal which allows user to save the given data. I want when user hit the Save button, system will store all input data to a XML file

Here is  my XML file:

```
<Begin>
  <Result name="CNF-359-vu-01212016-4-09-21" desc="This is a sample description"/>
  <Result name="CNF-365-admin-01222016-2-39-21" desc="This is a sample description 2"/>
</Begin>
```

My model function:

```
function addCNF(){

        //get the raw textdata of sample.xml
        $xmlRaw = file_get_contents(base_url(self::MANAGE_RESULT));

        //use the method to parse the data from xml

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlRaw);

        if ($xml === false) {
            echo "Failed loading XML: ";
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                echo "<br>", $error->message;
            }
            return false;
        } else {

            //insert to xml 
            $cnf = $xml->addChild('Result');
//          $cnf->addAttribute('name', '');
//          $cnf->addAttribute('desc', '');
            file_put_contents(self::MANAGE_RESULT, $xml->asXML()) or die("Error");
            formatXml(self::MANAGE_RESULT);
        }

        return "ok";
    }
```

My controller:

```
function addCNF(){
        if ($this->manageresult_model->addCNF() == "ok"){
            echo "Data save successfully!";
        } else {
                echo "Failed!"; 
            }
    }
```

My View:

```
$('#btnSaveChanges').on('click', function() {

    var post = '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/manage_result/addCNF';
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', cache:false,
        url : post,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(result) {

            var xml = "";

            var name = $('#CNFName').val();
            var desc = $('#CNFDesc').val();
            xml += "\t name = '" + name + "' desc ='" + desc + "'>\n";          

        $('#id_content').append(xml);

        },
        error:function() {
            alert('Unable to perform the request, please refresh page and try again later!');
        }
    });
    $('#myModal2').modal('toggle');

});
```

I don't know what should I do in View file so that system will store all the input data to XML file. Please advice!

Comment: this is backwards...you aren't posting any data to server where you should be updating xml and sending update in response No idea why you are using xml to store it though

Comment: I need to store it because this data will display in another different page

Comment: What @charlietfl is trying to say is, your AJAX is missing the 'data' attribute. No data is being posted to addCNF Page. You need to send the data you want to store in the XML file to the addCNF Page and then use those values in `$cnf->addAttribute` like `$cnf->addAttribute('name', $name);` and `$cnf->addAttribute('desc', $desc);`.

Comment: OK, I got it. Thanks kakashihatake2 and charlietfl alot :)